# Symfony 3 with GraphQL: authentication

Tags: symfony, authentication, graphql, fosuserbundle

I'm using Symfony 3 with youshido/graphql-bundle and FOSUserBundle. I'm beginning to work on the authentication part of the API and I don't know how to handle this with GraphQL.

What I found from my researches is that, usually, there is a REST endpoint to manage the user authentication but I would want to manage it with GraphQL and FOSUserBundle. Except, FOSUserBundle only offer REST endpoints and I don't know if there is a way to configure it so we can only use its services in the GraphQL resolvers.

The workflow I came up with is:

- User authenticates via GraphQL query and get a token generated by FOSUserBundle
- User sends a query/mutation with the token in the request headers
- FOSUserBundle verify this token and give access

How would you proceed?

Thank you!

Comment: Is FOSUserBundle a requirement ? Because all it does is giving you a User Entity and a bunch of routes & controllers. It could probably be easier for you to build your own authentication system with Symfony's Guard Authenticator. This way you would be fully flexible. The auth documentation is well done and covers API auth as well.

Comment: @Elbarto Thank you for your answer! FOSUserBundle is not a requirement but it would be nice if I could use some of their features instead of coding it myself

Comment: Well i understand the principle of not reinventing the wheel, but if a tool doesn't fully respond to a bunch of requirements, why would you use it :) ? In your case, i think you would save a lot of time by building your own authentication system instead of overiding / extending fosuserbundle. Here's good information : https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/guard_authentication.html#the-guard-authenticator-methods. FOSUserbundle uses symfony's authentication, so you can create your own authenticator (if you choose to still go for FOSUB)

Comment: @Elbarto I will look into building my own authentication system if tweaking FOSUB is too bothersome, thanks for your suggestion! Do you have by any chance a little experience with Symfony and GraphQL?

Comment: Symfony yes, GraphQL no. I was interested in GraphQL few months back, but i never really took the time to experiment it.